After deleting a OneSignal user tag son its website, The deleted tags get reverted after launching my app
My app is using OneSignal 4.8.9. After deleting user tags on the OneSignal website then relaunching the app, the deleted tags get added back on both the app and the site. Despite calling getTags() function, this issue persists. What might be causing this?
var oneSignalTags: JSONObject? = null

private fun updateOneSignalTags(callback: (JSONObject?) -> Unit) {
    OneSignal.getTags(callback)
}

updateOneSignalTags { tags ->
    MainActivity.oneSignalTags = tags
}

I have tried setting the external user ID and removing it. But they don't work.
OneSignal.setExternalUserId(OneSignal.getDeviceState()?.userId.toString())
OneSignal.removeExternalUserId()

